# Problem with 'Response Headers' values of File in Angular 4

Tags: angular, rest, http, response-headers

I have one webservice that returns a pdf file (byte[]) and the file name in the Response Headers.

I can see the values of 'Response Headers' on Chrome and everyone is there (including the file name). But I can't get this values on Angular becouse the headers value is just  "Content-Type:application/pdf".

My Angular Code:

```
  getPdf(url: string){

    http.get(url, {responseType: 'arraybuffer', observe:'response'})
        .subscribe(data => {
            console.log(data.headers.get('filename')); // print: null
            console.log(data.headers.keys()); // print: ["Content-Type"],
            downloadFile(data.body);
    });
  }
```

Response Headers on browser:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Origin, X-Request-Width, Content-Type, Accept, authCode
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Disposition:attachment; filename=file.pdf
Content-Type:application/pdf
Date:Mon, 26 Nov 2018 14:23:37 GMT
filename:file.pdf
Server:JBoss-EAP/7
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Powered-By:Undertow/1
```

Is there something wrong? How can I do this properly?

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem using the 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' on my webservice.

My java webservice:

```
    protected Response buildFile(Status status, byte[] file, String nomeArquivo) {
    return Response.status(status)
            .entity(file)
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
            .header("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Content-Disposition, filename")
            .header("Content-Type", "application/pdf")
            .header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="+ nomeArquivo)
            .header("filename", nomeArquivo)
            .build();
}
```

More info:
[How to get the name of a file downloaded with Angular5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50044299/how-to-get-the-name-of-a-file-downloaded-with-angular5)