# file-saver keep default file name of the file sended by node.js

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I'm having trouble trying to keep the backend file name when i'm downloading an file.

I'm using the file-saver: import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';

Then I have the following code:

saveAs( new Blob([resp]));

If I don't add the second argument then by default they set the following name:
[image]

if I copy and paste my GET request(url) in the browser. Its start correctly the download with the correct name.

I would like to do everything in the angular side. I don't want to add in the HTML the element

What is the best practice in this case?

or how I can extract the File name from the request

```
download() { let url = https://localhost:33/download return this.http.get(url, {responseType: 'blob' as 'json'}); }
```

Thank you

Comment: If the back send you the filename, then why you can't add it as the second param of `save` method ?

Comment: how I can extract the file name from the Blob? In my request I have the next:  download() {
    let url = https://localhost:33/download
    return this.http.get(url, {responseType: 'blob' as 'json'});
  }

Comment: Remove the `as 'json'` and add `observe: 'response'`. When you console log the response, what do you have ?

Comment: I think it's header issues from Backend, BTW It duplicates with (how-to-get-the-name-of-a-file-downloaded-with-angular5) [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50044299/how-to-get-the-name-of-a-file-downloaded-with-angular5]